# Is there some function like foreachGroup method in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I`m using Apache Spark to do some calculation. I run some query like this.

```
SELECT country, school, subjects, avg(score) FROM table GROUP BY country,school,subject
```

So the result is like :

```
USA, school1, math, 99
USA, school1, sport, 98
USA, school2, math, 90
ENG, school1, science, 100
```

Now for each school (represented by country + school_id), we need to get the top 3 subject based on their score.

I`m thinking two ways of doing this.

```
1. If there is some method called foreachGROUP, Then I will run code like

result.foreachGROUP(get_top_3)


2. I know there is a method called repartion. Then I guess I can do something like :

result.repartion( country,school ) # repartion by country and school
foreachPartion(get_top_3)
```

I`m not familiar with Apache spark. So not sure which way is possible or better. Please kindly give some advice. If you have better way than this. Please also adivce

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up your test data:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Rec("USA","school1", "math", 98.0),
  Rec("USA","school1", "lit", 96.0),
  Rec("USA","school1", "trig", 92.0),
  Rec("USA","school1", "eng", 94.0)
)).toDF
```

You do a `groupBy()`, wtih a `collect_list()` and then `explode` the top 3:

```
val top3bySchool = df.groupBy($"country", $"school")
  .agg(collect_list($"subject") as "subjectList", collect_list($"score") as "scoreList")
  .explode($"subjectList", $"scoreList"){r => {
    val subjectList = r.getSeq[String](0).zip(r.getSeq[Double](1)).sortWith((a,b) => {
      a._2 > b._2
    });
    subjectList.slice(0, if (subjectList.length < 3) subjectList.length else 3);
  }}.select($"country",$"school",$"_1" as "subject", $"_2" as "score")
```

Comment: Thanks  David. Are you using scala or JAVA? Because I `m not familiar with these two.  I am using python. Can you provided some examples with python?